# onTouchListener not accepting layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Code

```
private RelativeLayout mToolbar;
mToolbar = (RelativeLayout) myview.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

mToolbar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams updatedParameters = finalParameters;
        double x;
        double y;
        double pressedX;
        double pressedY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    x = updatedParameters.x;
                    y = updatedParameters.y;

                    pressedX = event.getRawX();
                    pressedY = event.getRawY();

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    updatedParameters.x = (int) (x + (event.getRawX() - pressedX));
                    updatedParameters.y = (int) (y + (event.getRawY() - pressedY));

                    wm.updateViewLayout(myview, updatedParameters);

                default:
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

I have a service and this above code can move around that service in the screen... It worked before when i had to touch a button and move it around. I switched it to layout now and it does.t work anymore
Why doesn't this work? The same code i used it with a button instead and it worked fine. Does onTouch always have to be button or can it be layouts or textviews as well?

Comment: your question title says onClick Listener while your code is using onTouch listener? And what doesn't work with above code

Comment: The code doesn't execute... according to the code i should be able to move the layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return `true` from onTouch method

If you return `false` when you get `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, 
Android assumes that you're not interested in handling touch events and simply doesn't pass any other motion events to you (including `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` that you're expecting)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the return part of onTouch Method

```
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // if return is true means touch enabled
    // If return is false means touch is disabled
    return true;
    }
```